# Google OpenID: the page you requested is invalid

Tags: openid, google-openid

I'm writing a Relying Party, and use the Google provider. Yadis leads me to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud, I create an association, and redirect the user's browser to that URL (HTTP 307), and fill in the following query parameters:

- openid.ns: `http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0`
- openid.mode: checkid_setup
- openid.assoc_handle: value_received_from_association,
- openid.return_to: `http://my_host:and_port/?returned=1`

AFAICT, I have filled out everything I'm supposed to provide, yet my user's browser gets a page from google which says "The page you requested is invalid". In what way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was literally triggered by not including the `openid.claimed_id` and `openid.identity` parameters, which must be set to `"http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select"`. With these set, I get another error, which can be resolved by also filling out `openid.realm`, with the same value as `openid.return_to`.

Even though I also implemented RP discovery, Google does not appear to use it.

Comment: Oh ya, don't know how I missed that.  :)  Actually, the OpenID spec allows for the absence of `openid.claimed_id` and `openid.identity`, but Google and most OPs don't actually support that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up RP discovery for your site yet?  That's something else you need to do, and Google might be enforcing it now.

http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/06/why-yahoo-says-your-openid-site.html

Comment: How could this possibly work? The only URL I give to google is the return_to URL, and I know for fact that Google is not trying to access it.