# OpenId Component: getting attributes back from Google using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, components, openid, cakephp-2.0

Is there an example that I can use to successfully get OpenId user attributes (like name, email) back from Google using CakePHP and the OpenID component? When I try and add required parameters, I get a "The page you requested is invalid."

### More detail

Component: http://code.42dh.com/openid/

If I don't request any "attributes", it works fine. As soon as I try and add a request for required / optional attributes as in the following example, I get an error from Google: "The page you requested is invalid."

Example (Not working for me): http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/02/12/using-the-openid-simple-registration-extension/

According to 1 source, the problem is:

> The error was literally triggered by not including the
>   openid.claimed_id and openid.identity parameters, which must be set to
>   "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select". With these set,
>   I get another error, which can be resolved by also filling out
>   openid.realm, with the same value as openid.return_to.

[Google OpenID: the page you requested is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344240/google-openid-the-page-you-requested-is-invalid)

**Code**

```
function openidlogin() {

    $realm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $returnTo = $realm . '/users/openidlogin';


    $url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id";
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isPost() && !$this->Openid->isOpenIDResponse()) {
        try {
            $this->Openid->authenticate($url, $returnTo, $realm); // WORKS !!!
            $this->Openid->authenticate($url, 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/users/login', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], array('email'), array()); // FAILS
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Error: Invalid OpenId");
        } catch (Exception $error) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Error: " + $error->getMessage());
        }
    } elseif ($this->Openid->isOpenIDResponse()) {

        $response = $this->Openid->getResponse($returnTo);

        if ($response->status == Auth_OpenID_CANCEL) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Google Login Cancelled");
            $this->redirect(array("controller" => "users", "action" => "login"));
        } elseif ($response->status == Auth_OpenID_FAILURE) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Veficiation Failed: " . $response->message);
            $this->redirect(array("controller" => "users", "action" => "login"));
        } elseif ($response->status == Auth_OpenID_SUCCESS) {

            $axResponse = Auth_OpenID_AX_FetchResponse::fromSuccessResponse($response);
            debug ($response);
            debug ($axResponse);
            $this->Session->setFlash("Authenticated");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following example: https://github.com/cakebaker/openid-component-example/blob/master/app/Controller/UsersController.php

Comment: I'm curious - how did you come up with that code? Were you already familiar with the OpenID library for php?

Comment: @Utkarsh: Yes, I'm the author of the OpenID component for CakePHP, which is based on the OpenID library for PHP.